# Bash bad variable substitution to extract a major number from a release

Tags: bash

I have a `CI_COMMIT_TAG` variable with the following sample value: `v12.23.34`.

I would like to extract the major part number of the tag on `CI_RELEASE_MAJOR`, meaning `12`.

Following [this documentation](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html), I did the following:

```
export CI_RELEASE_MAJOR=${${CI_COMMIT_TAG#v}%%.*}
```

This is working on `zsh`, but not on `bash`, giving the following error:

```
CI_RELEASE_MAJOR=${${CI_COMMIT_TAG#v}%%.*}: bad substitution
```

Why is it not working on bash and what is the proper way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh?

Comment: I don't know, was added by @Daniel Farrell.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it not working on bash

Because it's not possible to nest expansions like that.

> what is the proper way to achieve what I want?

The proper way is:

```
tmp=${CI_COMMIT_TAG#v}
CI_RELEASE_MAJOR=${tmp%%.*}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use regular-expression matching.

```
[[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ v([^.])*\. ]]
export CI_RELEASE_MAJOR=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```